# What formal proof systems are capable of proving $\forall x \exists y x = y$ without needing to apply $\forall$-I to $\exists y x = y$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, philosophy, modal-logic

I am interested in some philosophical questions that depend on whether the open formula $\exists y x = y$ is a *logical truth*. I'm making the assumption that some logical systems are *intended*, in the sense that conclusions of those logical systems are ones that ought to be philosophically endorsed. On that assumption, I can clarify what I mean by "logical truth." A logical truth is a statement for which there is a proof in a logical system that is intended (in the sense above). Thus, if standard predicate logic is intended, then the following proof shows that $\exists y x = y$ is a logical truth:

1. $x = x$ (axiom)
2. $\exists y x = y$ (1, $\exists$-I)

This conclusion is philosophically problematic for me. Since I think that all logical truths ought to be considered *metaphysically necessary*, this commits me to the conclusion that $\Box \exists y x = y$ is a necessary truth, which further leads to the conclusion that $\Box \forall x \Box \exists y x = y$ is a a logical truth. Properly understood, this is the sort of radical conclusion philosophers/logicians should avoid. It has the consequence, for example, that there is nothing that could have failed to be something.

So, I want a logical system in which $\exists y x = y$ never appears as a line in any proof. But there were reasons why it was needed in standard predicate logic. The primary example is in the question's titled. Usually one must prove $\exists y x = y$ "on the way" to proving $\forall x \exists y x = y$, which is harmless, philosophically speaking.

Comment: $\exists y(x = y)$ as such is an open sentence that has no truth value, to get one $x$ has to be quantified. The standard convention is to assume that unquantified variables are universally quantified, which makes it as harmless as  $\forall x \exists y(x = y)$. I am not sure what $\exists$-I means.

Comment: Not sure but a Hilbert-type system might be able to satisfy your requirements - and one not based on "generalization rules" but one more strictly adhering to the Hilbert-type system philosophy, i.e. it has axiom schemas like $(\forall x, \forall y, \phi) \rightarrow (\forall x, \phi[y := \tau])$ and $(\forall x, \phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow [(\forall x, \phi) \rightarrow (\forall x, \psi)]$.

Comment: I think you may be conflating technical issues in mathematical logic with philosophical issues. Specifically, as part of mathematics, mathematical logic is neutral as regards your metaphysical assumptions. You are making philosophical distinctions between free and bound variables that you need to clarify in mathematical terms.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a problem with first-order proof systems so much as a (philosophical) problem about modal logic and what "metaphysically necessary" means. When you write something like $\forall x\, \square P(x)$, what exactly do you mean? We can read this as "for all x, it's necessary that $P$ holds of $x$". Ok, so we pick some x "in this world". Is it true that "in every world", $P$ holds of $x$? It seems there are two ways to deal with this issue: One way is to decide that for every $x$ in a world, there is a canonical way to identify $x$ with an object in any accessible world. ...

Comment: ... Then the problem in your question goes away, because it's really true that "there's nothing that could have failed to be something". The other option is to decide that $\square P(x)$ is meaningless, or that it's false, whenever there's an accessible world that doesn't contain $x$. But then your rule that whenever you accept $\varphi(x)$ you are committed to $\square \varphi(x)$ is misguided.

Comment: I suspect you will be more successful if you first determine in full what you want your _semantics_ to be, before you go looking for a proof system.  Evidently your intended semantics is not the usual semantics of first-order logic, but just randomly looking for a proof system where $\exists y x = y$ does not appear in this proof is probably not going to fit your semantics much better.

Comment: In what sense $□∀x□∃yx=y$ is something we want to avoid ? Deos "there is nothing that could have failed to be something" means that you are interested into "non-existent" objects ? See [Alexius Meinong](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meinong/).

Comment: @Conifold, I'm not so worried about whether open formulas like this have a truth value. I'm more worried about ways they should be allowed to get bound in modal logic. Traditionally, modal logic has the "K" rule of inference: $\varphi \vdash \Box \varphi$. In such a proof system, it's difficult to understand what it would mean to say that all open formula are implicitly bound. That would render the following proof invalid: $Px \vee \neg Px \vdash \Box (Px \vee \neg Px) \vdash \forall x \Box (Px \vee \neg Px)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, I don't think that accepting $\varphi(x)$ commits you to accepting $\Box \varphi(x)$. Rather, I think that if you accept $\varphi(x)$ as a consequence of logic, you should accept $\Box \varphi(x)$ as a consequence of logic. The philosophical idea being that, whatever necessity is, it applies to logic; logic could not have worked differently, so its consequences should not change between possible worlds.

Comment: But if ∃y(x=y) has no truth value it can not possibly be a logical truth, let alone metaphysically necessary. It is just an unfinished building block for a proposition. I think you have in mind instantiated natural deduction formulas, where x is a name for "generic" individual in a subproof, at the end of which the variable is universally quantified. But a) instantiated formulas do not have the meaning you object to, and b) instantiation subproofs can be rewritten using closed formulas only even in the standard predicate calculus.

Comment: Regarding this being a philosophical problem about what "metaphysically necessary" means, I sort of accept that point. But I don't want to say this is just a question about meaning. I think there really is a deep philosophical issue at stake when you ask whether, for instance, there could have been fewer things than there are. On the "meaning" intended by $\Box \varphi$, The statement $\Box \forall x \Box \exists y x = y$ settles that issue. If everything is necessarily something, then there couldn't have been fewer things than there are...

Comment: I realize I haven't fully said what $\Box \varphi$ is supposed to mean, but I'm working on the assumption that this issue can be only partly settled in trying to determine what the "right" semantics and proof theory for $\Box \varphi$ should be.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I agree that the semantics should probably come first here, and I have a pretty good idea of what I think the semantics should be (something like Kripke-semantics with variable domains). But now there is the issue that I have the beginnings of a proof system which is not sound for the semantics. That seems to be a problem that needs resolved.

Comment: There is something called a "free logic" which let's you talk about things that don't necessarily exist.  That might be along the lines of what you are looking for.  Aside, what you call "intended" is usually called "sound".

Comment: @DanielIV, I intentionally avoided mentioning free logic, mostly because I don't know enough about it. My hope was that someone might explain how one goes about proving $\forall x \exists y x = y$ in free logic. But I think you're right, that is the ordinary solution to this problem. 
I want to distinguish between "sound" and "intended," because I'm mostly accustomed to "soundness" being a characteristic of a proof system relative to a semantics. That's certainly what I'm after, but I'm interested in a proof system that is sound for the "intended" semantics of modal logic.

Answer (score 1):

> What formal proof systems are capable of proving  ∀x∃yx=y  without needing to apply  ∀ -I to  ∃yx=y?

Formal proof by contradcition in [DC Proof](https://www.dcproof.com) system:

[image: Formal proof]

Comment: The existential specialization is basically the universal generalization. I mean you could (in classical logic) just go further and eliminate $\forall$ entirely by reducing it to $\neg\exists\neg$ (which you did as an intermediate step). That would get rid of $\forall$ introduction for sure.

Comment: @DerekElkins I have a form of $\forall$-intro in my system. It just isn't required in this proof.

Comment: My point is that $\forall$ introduction isn't required in *any* proof within a classical logic. (Of course, specific presentations of classical logic may require it but you could always make a slight variant to avoid that.) Arguably, the OP should  have a hang-up with either negation or existential specialization too.